# How do I solve this differential equation array?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have the following differential equation array,
$$ \frac{\mathrm d W}{\mathrm d t} = [1-aq(t-R_0) +b]{c\over q(t)+d } - [aq(t-R_0) - b]{W(t)\over q(t)+d}, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

$$ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\frac{\mathrm d q}{\mathrm d t} = {W(t)\over q(t)+d } -e, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

where $a, b, c, d, e, R_0$ are constants. $q(t-R_0)$ denotes $q(t)$ with time delay $R_0$.

How can I solve it? I don't expect any closed-form expression for $W(t)$ and $q(t)$, numerical solutions with tools like matlab are welcome.

Comment: This is a delay-differential equation (DDE), many ODE packages have specialized solver procedures for that.

Comment: @LutzL could you please find an example of matlab? What worries me is that can I directly input the term $q(t-R_0)W(t)/(q(t)+d)$ into matlab? Most examples I find are solving linear differential equation systems.

Comment: No, you can not access the state at a different time in a rhs function that you pass to an ODE solver. The rhs function of an ODE system is all at the same time, no connection of different times possible. That's why you need a DDE solver. Also note that by including the state at $t-R_0$ in the dynamic you depend on all states in-between. Especially the initial condition is not a state, but a function on an interval of length $R_0$. See for instance this [example from the Matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/dde-with-constant-delays.html).

Comment: @LutzL I have looked at the example. $y_2'(t) = y_1(t-1) + y_2(t-0.2)$, where $y_1(t-1) + y_2(t-0.2)$ is an linear sum, while in my question I have $W(t)$ and $q(t)$ in the numerator and denominator, can matlab still solve it?

Comment: Yes, you get in the argument $Z$ full access to the approximation of the state at time $t-R_0$. You can then combine the state arguments at $t$ and $t-R_0$ any way you want or need, also non-linearly. Be aware of the singularities close to divisions by zero.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks! I have got the result, just did it in this way.